# video stops playing in mac 10.7.5 once file is closed and reopened

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint

Inserted videos don't play in powerpoint after file is closed and reopened. They play when first inserted, but then once the presentation is closed and then reopened, the videos don't play. They aren't even recognized as a video

Comment: Any format? Which version of PowerPoint are you using? Is it up to date?